# identity for quaternions' group Sp(n)=Sp(2n,C)∩U(2n)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, quaternions

Could you help me for solving this:
Let $Sp(n)$ be the group of linear transformations of $H^n$ such that preserve hermitian form 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \overline{q_i}r_i,$$
that $H$ is the quaternions _ the non-commutative generalization of the complex numbers_, then we have $Sp(n)= Sp(2n,C)\cap U(2n)$, that $C$ is complex number.

[I mean : if $q= x+iy+ju+kv$ then $\overline{q}= x- iy-ju-kv$]

Comment: Please check that I Texified your formulas correctly. Also, read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen , Thanks, I did't know that! Yes it is correct.